# Login failed error with Twitter Sdk for Android

Tags: android, twitter

I get a login failed message with the twitter sdk for android.This is because an instance of the twitter login is already running.How do I stop this instance so that I can login again and avoid the login failed error.

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: This is the layout file             <com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
        android:id="@+id/twitter_login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: twitterLoginButton.setCallback(loginPresenter.twitterLoginCallback());

Comment: @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        twitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CREATE_PROFILE) {
            loginPresenter.onCreateProfileFinished();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

Comment: This is in the presenter.                                                                            public Callback<TwitterSession> twitterLoginCallback() {
        return twitterHandler.twitterLoginCallback(this);
    }

Comment: Got code from here.https://fabric.io/kits/android/twitterkit/features